# Video loops and pauses

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I'm making a web app for a gym, I need on a specific page to show a video of an exercise and repeat it for the number of repetitions, example 10 times, then I need to have a pause according to the set recovery time, example 60 seconds, and then I need to repeat this cycle for the set series, example 3.

This is the code that doesn't work for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    function sleep(milliseconds) {
        const date = Date.now();
        let currentDate = null;
        do {
            currentDate = Date.now();
        } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
    }

    
    var player_video=document.getElementById("player");

    var rep_video=parseInt(<?php echo($rep_video)?>);
    var ser_video=parseInt(<?php echo($ser_video)?>);
    var rec_video=parseInt(<?php echo($rec_video)?>);
    rec_video = rec_video * 1000;
    
    var count_rep=0;
    var count_ser=0;
    player_video.onended = function() {
        if(count_ser<ser_video){                
            while(count_rep < rep_video){
                player_video.src ="video/<?php echo($src_video)?>";
                player_video.load();
                player_video.play();
                count_rep++;                    
            }
            count_ser++;
            count_rep=0;
            sleep(rec_video);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: You don't need and definitely should not use a sleep function in client-side Javascript.  The onended handler should trigger when the video ends, you don't need to tie up the main thread sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest 1 video for your reps that you loop through, and a second video that shows the recovery countdown?  That way - if they want to skip ahead, they can do so pretty easily.